# ToastActivatorCLSID missing from AppUserModel

Tags: c#

im an currently following this guide to add windows toast notifications to my app. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop

i need to create a shortcut that contains the System.AppUserModel.ID and System.AppUserModel.ToastActivatorCLSID.

now the website says to just have your installer create this and they recommend using WIX. which is fine but i would rather just create the shortcut from C# code.
so there is this example that creates the shortcut via C#.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/sending-toast-notifications-71e230a2
but it only shows adding the AppUserModel.ID and not the ToastActivatorCLSID...
here is some of that code...

```
private void InstallShortcut(String shortcutPath)
    {
        // Find the path to the current executable
        String exePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
        IShellLinkW newShortcut = (IShellLinkW)new CShellLink();

        // Create a shortcut to the exe

ShellHelpers.ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcut.SetPath(exePath));

ShellHelpers.ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcut.SetArguments(""));

        // Open the shortcut property store, set the AppUserModelId     property
        IPropertyStore newShortcutProperties = (IPropertyStore)newShortcut;

        using (PropVariant appId = new PropVariant(APP_ID))
        { 

ShellHelpers.ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.SetValue(System Properties.System.AppUserModel.ID, appId));

ShellHelpers.ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.Commit());
        }

        // Commit the shortcut to disk
        IPersistFile newShortcutSave = (IPersistFile)newShortcut;


ShellHelpers.ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutSave.Save(shortcutPath,  true));
    }
```

the thing is that the AppUserModel does not have a ToastActivatorCLSID property. seems strange.
i figured i could just add another using block to add the ToastActivatorCLSID property like this

```
using (PropVariant clsId = new PropVariant(CLSID))
        { 

ShellHelpers.ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.SetValue(System Properties.System.AppUserModel.ToastActivatorCLSID, CLSID));

ShellHelpers.ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.Commit());
        }
```

but the SystemProperties.System.AppUserModel.ToastActivatorCLSID doesnt exist.
right now the appuser model is coming from Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem.
this page shows it should exist
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/properties/props-system-appusermodel-toastactivatorclsid
i would if with that information i could make some kind of interface or something to add in that ToastActivatorCLSID.

there is very little on the internet on this topic. Don't know if there is a different reference or something.

any help would be great

Answer (score 2):

I've been running into the same problem and I've found a work around.

1. Clone this github repo: https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1
2. open the WindowsAPICodePack12.sln in visual studio.
3. open Shell > PropertySystem > SystemProperties.cs
4. find the `AppUserModel` class on line 2302
5. add this code to the class:

   ```
    public static PropertyKey ToastActivatorCLSID
    {
        get
        {
            PropertyKey key = new PropertyKey(new Guid("{9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}"), 26);

            return key;
        }
    }
   ```
6. Build the project. Open the bin folder (where the built projects go) and find `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.dll` and `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.dll`
7. Reference these dlls in your project instead of the original code pack.